# Cannot set UITableView frame on XCode Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this code on `- viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.viewContainer addSubview:self.tableView];
    float w = self.viewContainer.frame.size.width;
    float h = self.viewContainer.frame.size.height;
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
    NSLog(@"h = %f", h);
    NSLog(@"viewContainer.height = %f", self.viewContainer.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"tableView.height = %f", self. tableView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Whenever this code ran, I see on the console log. Here's the result:

```
h = 623.000000
viewContainer.height = 623.000000
tableView.height = 0.000000
```

Why? What's wrong with my attempt to set the dimension of tableView?

Comment: Maybe, your `tableView` is `nil` i.e uninitialized?

Comment: @FahriAzimov sorry, I just move the entire code block into viewWillAppear, and it works. I don't know why it is a thing. I thought it doesn't matter whether it's on viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear. Thanks.

Comment: It does matter where do you call this method. [Read more about VC life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch size updating, try to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of UIViewController.
But also, using `addSubview` in `viewWillAppear` or in `viewDidAppear` is not the best practice, because it will be added each time when ViewController appears (for example when you will return to it in Navigation stack)

Comment: Yeah, I've figured it out after trying it around. But I didn't know that addSubView in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear is not good. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

With setFrame: you should put code to `viewDidLayoutSubview`. In `viewDidAppear` just element load from `xib` or `storyboard` so frame in here will same on there. In `viewDidLayoutSubview` frame have exact where they should.

If you want set in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidload` you should add constraint in there, it will right frame you want.

For add constraint to child view to parent view you can try my snip set code: [Convenient add constraint for childviewcontroller.view and containerview](https://gist.github.com/vienvu89/07c7fcaef5dcdc627ab0)

Comment: My project is using auto layout. Therefore I can't add constraint. But you gave some insight about what the viewDidAppear did, which may be useful to know for the future. Thanks!

Comment: @ChenLiYong You can try my convenient for add autolayout on this case.

Comment: @ChenLiYong make sure add yourSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; too.

Comment: I see, so that won't messed up with my newly added constraint by code. Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply view controller frame directly to the tableview like,

```
CGRect frame = self.viewContainer.frame;
self.tableView.frame = frame;
```

Try this code, it will work.

Comment: It doesn't work, if I do it from viewDidAppear. It simply just return 0 for width and height if I print it using NSLog. It works if I do it from viewWillAppear. Anyway, I've finally solved my whole problem by moving the whole code block to viewWillLayoutSubviews, but I'm just curious, why this strange behaviour happened with viewDidAppear, as everywhere I see on the internet about setting component size, people always suggest putting code inside viewDidAppear.